# Redis Sentinel with 2 master after multi az netsplit

Tags: redis, sentinel, redis-sentinel

Hello stack community,

I have a question about Redis sentinel for a specific problem case. I use AWS with Multi AZ to create a sensu cluster.

On eu-central-1a I have a sensu+redis(M), a RBMQ+Sentinel and 2 others Sentinels. Same on eu-central-1b but the redis is my slave on this AZ.

What happen if there is a problem and eu-central-1a can not communicate with eu-central-1b ? What I think is that Sentinel on eu-central-1b should promote my redis slave to master, because he can not contact my redis master. So I should have 2 redis masters running together on 2 different AZ.

But when the link is retrieved between AZ, I will still have 2 masters, with 2 different datas. What will happen in this case ? One master will become a slave and data will be replicated without loss ? Do we need to restart a master and he will be a slave ?

Answer (score 0):

Sentinel detects changes to the master for example

If the master goes down and is unreachable a new slave is elected. This is based on the `quorum` where multiple sentinels agree that the master has gone down. The `failover` then occurs.

Once the sentinel detects the master come back online it is then a slave I believe thus the new master continues I believe. You will loose data in the switchover from master to new master that in inevitable.

If you loose connection then yes sentinel wont work correctly as it relies on multiple sentinels to agree the master redis is down. You shouldn't use sentinel in a 2 sentinel system.

Basic solution would be for you to put a extra sentinel on another server maybe the client/application server that isn't running redis/sentinel this way you can make use of the `quorum` and sentinels agreeing the master is down.